# Filling an ArrayLists with n elements to a specific sum

Tags: java, arraylist

Currently I'm working through some exercises in my book where I'm solving a problem on bulgarian solitaire ( The chapter is on arrays and arraylists).

The basic idea is to start with a list of numbers (randomly sized) as long as they sum to 45 say `20, 5, 1, 9, and 10` you give one and make another stack like the following

```
20, 5, 1, 9, and 10 -> 19, 4, 8, 10, and 5.
```

Eventually if you keep doing this you will get a stack like

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9
```

I'm having trouble with the first start of the problem where I fill the arraylist with a specific amount of items, as long as they sum to 45. The following is my code

```
class organizeCards
{
    private int sum;
    private Random randNum;
    private boolean flag;
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums;
    public organizeCards()
    {
        sum = 0;
        randNum = new Random();
        flag = true;
        nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public void fillArrList()
    {
        int nextNum = 0;
        while(flag)
        {
            int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(45 - nextNum) + 1;
            System.out.println(thisRandNum);
            nums.add(thisRandNum);
            sum+=thisRandNum;
            nextNum = thisRandNum;
            if(sum == 45)
            {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Heres my Issue ( I know my problem, just not really sure how to fix it)

My code is doing the following.

First get a random number from `1-45`, say `30`

Now `45-30 = 15`, so the next random number can be from `1-15`

Now Say `8`

Now our rand number is from `1-7` This process will keep repeating, but won't eventually If I keep adding these my sum reach `45`?

What am I missing in my logic?

**EDIT(Oops I put sum > 45 in my own code)**

Currently, my program sometimes ends and gives me an arraylist that is proper size. But often times never terminates.

Comment: Change it to `nextNum = sum`

Comment: I tried, and it gives me "bound must be positive", but that doesent make much sense to me anyways. Don't I want to subtract whatever the old random Number is from 45, to get the new bounds for the new random number?

Comment: How about after your edit?

Comment: Got it, much appreciated!

Comment: Please check out my answer below as well.

Comment: There's honestly no need to use `nextNum`, it just obfuscates the code. Just use `sum` in this line: `int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(45 - sum) + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code:

```
while(flag)
    {
        int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(45 - nextNum) + 1;
        System.out.println(thisRandNum);
        nums.add(thisRandNum);
        sum+=thisRandNum;
        nextNum = thisRandNum;
        if(sum == 45)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

Here, you are subtracting `nextNum` from `45` to get the maximum number achieved. However, what you wish to do is subtract the sum of all the previous numbers generated from the `random()` function.

Changed code:

```
while(flag)
{
    int thisRandNum = randNum.nextInt(45 - nextNum) + 1;
    System.out.println(thisRandNum);
    nums.add(thisRandNum);
    sum+=thisRandNum;
    nextNum = sum;
    if(sum == 45)
    {
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh... I see.. This makes sense. I was really pulling my hair over this for like half an hour. Thanks alot!

Comment: @JonnyHenly True but I did not want to change OPs code much.